# how to rewind filechannel

Tags: java, filechannel

in my homework we need to use `fc.position(position)` to locate the contents, but after that I need to rewind fc in order to recursive do this, what should I do, it seems there is no rewind method for fc

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider

```
fc.position(0);
```

?

But if you're using position() consistently, I don't see why you also need a rewind.